# Applying a function to every row on each n number of columns in R

Tags: r, data.table, apply

My data contains consecutive columns 1,2,...,2000. I want to apply a functions that returns a 3 vars for each group of 100 columns for each row.

The data look like this:

```
  1       2        3    .....   2000  
0.01    0.0       0.002         0.03
0.005   0.002     0.011         0.04
0.001   0.003     0.004         0.0
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
prep_data <- function(df){
  #Create Column names
  colnms<-c()
  for(i in seq(1, 20, 1)){
    
    for(j in seq(1, 3, 1)){
      f<-paste0("grp",i,"_",j)
      colnms=c(colnms,f)
    }
    
  }
  #
  trans <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 60, nrow = NROW(df)))
  colnames(trans) <-colnms

#Looping over every row
  for (i in 1:NROW(df)){
      X = c()
      #LOOPING over each group of 100 columns
      for(j in seq(1, 1900, 100)){
        end<-j+99
        tmp<-subset(df[i], select=j:end)
        #Here I apply the function over the 100 columns for the current row to get 3 values#
          X = c(X,MY_FUNC(tmp))
         ###################################################################################          
}
      }
#Append the current row
      trans[i,] <- X
  }
  return(trans)
  
}
```

The expected output (A dataframe of 60 columns) is as follows:

```
grp1_1  grp1_2    grp1_3 .....  grp20_3  
0.01    0.0       0.002         0.03
0.005   0.002     0.011         0.04
0.001   0.003     0.004         0.0
```

My code runs but its too slow probably because it's not efficient with all the loops

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does MY_FUNC do?

Comment: Please also provide a small example maybe of the first 20 columns of your data with dput(df)

Comment: MY_FUNC aggregates the 100 values  and returns a vector of 3 values

Comment: Yes, but what kind of aggregation? E.g. if it as sth. like mean, median, sd or so, there might be a more efficient way. And even if not, it would help to find the bottleneck in your code, so providing the content of your function + some data would be a minimum requirement to help you.

Comment: In fact PCA is used to select only 3 features

Comment: then I repeat myself that we need a small example of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

Let `d` be your 3 rows x 2000 columns frame, with column names `as.character(1:2000)` (See below for generation of fake data). We add a row identifier using `.I`, then melt the data long, adding `grp`, and column-group identifier (i.e. identifying the 20 sets of 100). Then apply your function `myfunc` (see below for stand-in function for this example), by row and group, and swing wide. (I used `stringr::str_pad` to add 0 to the front of the group number)

```
# add row identifier
d[, row:=.I]

# melt and add col group identifier
dm = melt(d,id.vars = "row",variable.factor = F)[,variable:=as.numeric(variable)][order(variable,row), grp:=rep(1:20, each=300)]

# get the result (180 rows long), applying myfync to each set of columns, by row
result = dm[, myfunc(value), by=.(row,grp)][,frow:=rep(1:3,times=60)]

# swing wide (3 rows long, 60 columns wide)
dcast(
  result[,v:=paste0("grp",stringr::str_pad(grp,2,pad = "0"),"_",row)],
  frow~v,value.var="V1"
  )[, frow:=NULL][]
```

Output: (first six columns only)

```
      grp01_1    grp01_2    grp01_3    grp02_1    grp02_2    grp02_3
        <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>
1: 0.54187168 0.47650694 0.48045694 0.51278399 0.51777319 0.46607845
2: 0.06671367 0.08763655 0.08076939 0.07930063 0.09830116 0.07807937
3: 0.25828989 0.29603471 0.28419957 0.28160367 0.31353016 0.27942687
```

Input:

```
d = data.table()
alloc.col(d,2000)
set.seed(123)
for(c in 1:2000)  set(d,j=as.character(c), value=runif(3))
```

`myfunc` Function (toy example for this answer):

```
myfunc <- function(x) c(mean(x), var(x), sd(x))
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Just a question plz, for more rows I guess I have to replace 300 by NROW()*100 and times replaced by NROW()*20

Comment: yes, that's correct; the "3" in `frow:=rep(1:3...)`, refers to the length of the vector returned by `myfunc()`. The `times` is the number of rows x the number of column groups (or in this case 3 x 20 = 60).

Comment: It worked with all the rows by changing also ```frow``` with ```row``` as follows: 
```R
dcast(
  result[,v:=paste0("grp",stringr::str_pad(grp,2,pad = "0"),"_",frow)],
   row~v,value.var="V1"
  )[, frow:=NULL][]
```